# Check if a string contains any substring in an array in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am studying PowerShell. I want to know how to check  if a string contains any substring in an array in  PowerShell. I know how to do the same in Python. The code is given below:

```
any(substring in string for substring in substring_list)
```

Is there similar code available in PowerShell?

My PowerShell code is given below.

```
$a = @('one', 'two', 'three')
$s = "one is first"
```

I want to validate $s with $a. If any string in $a is present in $s then return True. Is it possible in PowerShell?

Answer (score 33):

Using the actual variables in the question for simplicity:

```
$a = @('one', 'two', 'three')
$s = "one is first"
$null -ne ($a | ? { $s -match $_ })  # Returns $true
```

Modifying $s to *not* include anything in $a:

```
$s = "something else entirely"
$null -ne ($a | ? { $s -match $_ })  # Returns $false
```

(That's about 25% fewer characters than [chingNotCHing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31603685/185123), using the same variable names of course :-)

Comment: I like this answer, it's short, it's sweet, it works. I think that there just needs some explaination for understanding what is happening. After reading chingNotCHing's answer, I understood it a little better.

Comment: Instead of contains, I want to replace all array elements if contained in a string. I would use: $neu=(',','.' |%{ 'abc,.'.replace($_,'')}), but does not work because it repeats the string: abc. abc,

Answer (score 17):

```
($substring_list | %{$string.contains($_)}) -contains $true
```

should strictly follow your one-liner

Comment: Best answer because it does not struggle on any unexpected regex-characters.

Answer (score 13):

#### For PowerShell ver. 5.0+

Instead of,

```
$null -ne ($a | ? { $s -match $_ })
```

try this simpler version:

```
$q = "Sun"
$p = "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
[bool]($p -match $q)
```

This returns `$True` if substring `$q` is in the array of string `$p`.

Another Example:

```
if ($p -match $q) {
    Write-Host "Match on Sun !"
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer at this point. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: This is backwards. The question is about substrings _of_ `$q` not `$p`.

Comment: Vimes is right. The question is how you search elements of an array in a string. This answer is showing how to search for a string in the elements of an array. It's the opposite. Downvoted.

Comment: But @Michael Koza answered the question *I have*.  ;)

Answer (score 8):

I'm amazed that in 6 years nobody has given this more simple and readable answer

```
$a = @("one","two","three")
$s = "one1 is first"

($s -match ($a -join '|')) #return True
```

So simply implode the array into a string using vertical bar "|" , as this is the alternation (the "OR" operator) in regex.
https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html
https://blog.robertelder.org/regular-expression-alternation/

Also keep in mind that the accepted answer will not search for exact match. If you want exact match you can use the \b (word boundary)
https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

```
$a = @("one","two","three")
$s = "one1 is first"

($s -match '\b('+($a -join '|')+')\b') #return False
```

Answer (score 7):

[Michael Sorens' code answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603128/check-if-a-string-contains-any-substring-in-an-array-in-powershell/31620141#31620141) works best to avoid the pitfall of partial substrings matching. It just needs a slight regex modification. If you have the string `$s = "oner is first"`, the code would still return true since 'one' would match 'oner' (a match in PowerShell means the second string contains the first string.

```
$a = @('one', 'two', 'three')
$s = "oner is first"
$null -ne ($a | ? { $s -match $_ })  # Returns $true
```

Add some regex for word boundary '\b' and the r on 'oner' will now return false:

```
$null -ne ($a | ? { $s -match "\b$($_)\b" })  # Returns $false
```

Answer (score 3):

(I know it's an older thread but at least I might help people looking at this in the future.)

Any response given that uses -match will produce incorrect answers.
Example: $a -match $b will produce false negatives if $b is "."

A better answer would be to use .Contains - but it's case sensitive so you'd have to set all strings to upper or lower case before comparing:

```
$a = @('one', 'two', 'three')
$s = "one is first"
$a | ForEach-Object {If ($s.toLower().Contains($_.toLower())) {$True}}
```

Returns $True

```
$a = @('one', 'two', 'three')
$s = "x is first"
$a | ForEach-Object {If ($s.toLower().Contains($_.toLower())) {$True}}
```

Returns nothing

You could tweak it to return $True or $False if you'd want, but IMO the above is easier.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this:

```
$array = @("test", "one")
$str = "oneortwo"
$array|foreach {
    if ($str -match $_) {
        echo "$_ is a substring of $str"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to select a subset of strings containing any of the strings like this:

```
$array = @("a", "b")
$source = @("aqw", "brt", "cow")

$source | where { 
    $found = $FALSE
    foreach($arr in $array){
        if($_.Contains($arr)){
            $found = $TRUE
        }
        if($found -eq $TRUE){
            break
        }
    }
    $found
  }
```