# How to delete all merged local branches in Git with PowerShell

Tags: git, powershell

How can I iterate through my branches, filter out merged branches and delete them using Git for Windows in Powershell?

I have already attempted some research, but every answer I have found revolves around using bash specific commands, such as grep and xargs. Powershell does not have the same commands so these do not work for me.

However, from that research I have found that `git for-each-ref --format '%(refname:short)' refs/heads` can show me all local branches, while `git branch -d` will delete any merged branch. However, piping these two commands together (`git for-each-ref --format '%(refname:short)' refs/heads | git branch -d`) does not work as the output from the first command is not piped as I expected.

Comment: `git branch --merged master` will provide you the list of branches merged to `master` (including `master` itself). Maybe you can work on this base to pipe it to `git branch -d`. I don't know Powershell, so I won't be of any help on that subject.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After some playing about, and further research into PowerShell commands, I have found a solution!

While PowerShell does not have an `xargs` command, it does have something similar called `ForEach-Object`. This command allows us to work on each line of the output from `git for-each-ref`. For this specific problem, the following line did the trick:

```powershell
git for-each-ref --format '%(refname:short)' refs/heads | 
ForEach-Object { git branch $_ -d }
```

The curly braces after the `ForEach-Object` command contains the command you wish to run, while the `$_` variable stands for each line of output from the piped command.

Hope this helps other newbie PowerShell/Git users out there!

Comment: Nice! You may want to add `--merged` just before your pipe to limit it to merged branches

Comment: I added a check to exclude develop and master from being deleted as well...

`git for-each-ref --format '%(refname:short)' refs/heads --merged | ForEach-Object { If("develop","master" -notcontains $_) { git branch $_ -d } }`

Comment: oh, nice @unforgiven1987, exactly what i wanted to do.. score! 

Comment: Added check for 'main' aswell as 'master'. 
`git for-each-ref --format '%(refname:short)' refs/heads --merged | ForEach-Object { If("develop","master","main" -notcontains $_) { git branch $_ -d } }`

Answer (score 7):

`git branch --merged | Select-String -Pattern '^[^\*].*' | ForEach-Object { git branch -d $_.ToString().Trim() }`

Steps:

1. List merged branches: `git branch --merged`

   ```
     feature/branch1
     feature/branch2
   * master
   ```
2. Filter out those that starts with * (current branch): `Select-String -Pattern '^[^\*].*'`

   ```
     feature/branch1
     feature/branch2
   ```
3. Delete branches `ForEach-Object { git branch -d $_.ToString().Trim() }`

Notice than in #3 I have removed some whitespace from the output: `$_.ToString().Trim()`.
Otherwise we would get errors like:

```
error: branch '  feature/yourbranch' not found.
```

Answer (score 4):

As a complement to `Liero`'s answer, you can use the following regex for excluding specific branches from the list of branches that are going to be deleted:

```
'^(?!.*(master|development)).*$'
```

Hence the full command becomes:

```
git branch --merged | Select-String -Pattern '^(?!.*(master|development|main)).*$' | ForEach-Object { git branch -d $_.ToString().Trim() }
```

**PS**: If your branches names contains non ascii characters you may have to switch Powershell's output encoding before running the command above, for instance:

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this command:

```
git branch | %{ $_.Trim() } | ?{ $_ -ne 'master' } | %{ git branch -D $_ }
```

All credits to [Andrei Fedotov](https://dev.to/koscheyscrag/git-how-to-delete-all-branches-except-master-2pi0)

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to use the above solution from S.Harris in powershell version  5.1.  The "if" statement wasn't capturing the desired pattern.  Making the following modification worked for me:

````
```
git for-each-ref --format '%()' refs/heads | ForEach-Object 
{if($_.contains("<some_string>")){git branch -d $_}}
```
````

Apparently the powershell API was modified to include the `contains()` as a class method for all strings [see an example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2).  I referenced the answer from [chingnotCHing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603128/check-if-a-string-contains-any-substring-in-an-array-in-powershell) in my research.

Answer (score 0):

I use `git branch -d (git branch).split()` this will output some errors, because it can't delete current branch, and should be safe because we are using lower case `-d` meaning only merged ones get deleted. It will also output some errors because of the simple split will return some new lines and invalid branch names, but should be fine.

This works by getting all branches found by the command `git branch`, and then we use PowerShell's split method to split the return into an array. That array is then fed into the `git branch -d`, which deletes only merged branches.