# Azure devops pipeline CmdLine Task script error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Hi I am new to AzureDevops and pipelines, I am trying to create a CmdLine Task With a script that sets some variables based on the branch name here the script :

> ```
> - task: CmdLine@2
>   displayName: Find Branch type
>   inputs:
>    script: |
>      IF contains($(Build.SourceBranch), 'release')==True (set isLongBranch=True
>       ) ELSE IF contains($(Build.SourceBranch), 'support') (set isLongBranch=True
>       ) ELSE IF contains($(Build.SourceBranchName), 'develop') (set isLongBranch=True
>       ) ELSE IF contains($(Build.SourceBranchName), 'master') (set isLongBranch=True
>       ) ELSE IF contains($(Build.SourceBranch), 'hotfix') (set isLongBranch=True
>       ) ELSE (set isLongBranch=False)
>      IF contains($(Build.SourceBranch), 'release') (set isSonar=True
>       ) ELSE IF contains($(Build.SourceBranch), 'support'), 'support')] (set isSonar=True
>       ) ELSE IF contains($(Build.SourceBranchName), 'develop') (set isSonar=True
>       ) ELSE IF contains($(Build.SourceBranchName), 'master') (set isSonar=False
>       ) ELSE IF contains($(Build.SourceBranch), 'hotfix') (set isSonar=True
>       ) ELSE IF contains($(Build.SourceBranch), 'feature') (set isSonar=True
>       ) ELSE IF %isPoolRequest%==True (set isSonar=False
>       ) ELSE (set isSonar=False)
>       #echo $(Build.SourceBranch)
>       #echo $(Build.SourceBranchName)
> ```

The error I get is :

'release')==True was unexpected.
##[error]Cmd.exe has stopped. exit code : '255'.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure devops pipeline CmdLine Task script error

I got the same error with you, if I use the same code as you.

Generally, we use the `findstr` to check if the variable contains substring, like:

```
echo $(Build.SourceBranch) | findstr "release" >nul &&(
    echo "include"
)
```

Alternatively, you could use powershell scripts to do this:

```
$files = @("$(Build.SourceBranch)")
$excludeTypes = @("*release*","*support*", "*master*")

    foreach ($type in $excludeTypes) {
        if ($file -like $type) { 
            Write-Host ("Match found: {0} matches {1}" -f $file, $type)
            $Env:isLongBranch = true
        } 
          else
        {
          $Env:isLongBranch = False
        }
    }
```

You could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603128/check-if-a-string-contains-any-substring-in-an-array-in-powershell) for some more details.